# How to use "Try this API" explorer for Pub/Sub

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-pubsub, google-apis-explorer

[image: API Explorer setup]

After entering the relevant values, I am getting 403 error (see screenshot)

I then noticed that the API Explorer does not have a way for me to input my API key. So, I copy pasted the provided JS code and tried to run it manually, after having inserted the API key that I created.

But still, I was getting the same error. After some digging, I found [this link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) which says that only..

> A limited number of GCP services allow access using only an API key

And Pub/Sub is not one of them.

---

So:

**1. Am I correct in believing that Pub/Sub requires some additional auth (by way of service or user account) and that its API cannot be used with simple an API key?**

(And in case, a Googler is reading:)

2. If yes, I believe the API Explorer should reflect this fact and not provide boilerplate code which leads one to think the reverse is true.
3. There should be a way to provide the API key in order to execute the code from within the API Explorer itself.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, Cloud Pub/Sub does not support API keys as an authentication method. Instead, in the API Explorer, under the ‘Credentials’ dropdown, and select [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to used for authentication.

For more information: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/authentication